# ZeroMQ and SELinux

Tags: zeromq, selinux

I have a python web application that uses ZeroMQ for the communication between front-end and back-end servers (RedHat 6).
Everything works fine, but only with SELinux disabled (or Permissive).

Someone of you managed to use ZeroMQ with SELinux in Enforcing mode?

Here is the error in my Apache log with SELinux enabled:

```
Permission denied (signaler.cpp:120)
[Thu Nov 27 18:02:17 2014] [notice] child pid 5787 exit signal Aborted (6)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have moved on from here now, however, in case it helps, SELinux with Apache requires that CGI script files have the SELinux TYPE attribute set to `httpd_sys_script_exec_t`.

These links have helped me:

[SELinux](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7-Beta/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Confined_Services-The_Apache_HTTP_Server-Types.html)

[semanage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/semanage)

Please check documentation for confirmation/clarification of the above.

Use of the `ls -Z` command will reveal the SELinux attributes of any file/dir.